# How to decide if now is a good time to buy tickets for trips far in the future because of prices being reduced by COVID-19?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, covid-19

Of course this isn't the time to travel, but with prices so low, how can I decide if now the time to buy tickets for future trips?

I was looking into traveling to Europe or Japan from the United States. While there is a lot of uncertainty right now, it seems like a good time to buy for later travel.

In my case I was thinking about tickets for late in the year (not before October). I have also heard that COVID-19 could also "completely cancel" 2020. I would love to hear some other thoughts on this.

Comment: Reopened as I believe it's not objectively answerable for every person, but you can provide the information as below to help them make the decision, and I've edited the question to be less subjective.

Comment: I guess I didn't word it very well but this question was more about risk and risk tolerance when buying tickets than any specific travel plans.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone here has a crystal ball. It's nearly impossible to know if the current pandemic will be over and dealt with in 2 months, 3, 6, a year, 2 years...

Comment: I expect the price reduction to roughly match the uncertainty, so on average, you should feel about the same way about buying cheap tickets now, as you would feel about buying expensive tickets when there isn't a pandemic and a stock market crash.

Comment: "I was looking at traveling to Europe or Japan from the United States" London - New York seems to still be its normal price for the rest of the year (based on Google Flights). So I guess you're looking at more niche routes?

Comment: I think we have to clearly define what is too ephemeral to be asked here. [What is our stance on questions on airlines/governments' activities/policies pertaining to COVID-19? On-topic or off-topic as too ephemeral?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6520/1810) Currently closing/reopening COVID-19 questions seems quite random.

Comment: Depends which airlines you are certain of not to file for bankruptcy.

Comment: This question seems to roughly come down to asking when COVID-19 will blow over, or how we'll know when we're out of the woods. No-one knows the former and you should refer to medical experts for the latter (although there's also the lasting effect on the economy, which may be harder to judge). As for buying tickets before it has blown over, that's basically gambling because you don't know how likely are any of the many factors which would affect whether you can actually take the trip.

Comment: What makes you think the airline or third party company you buy with still exist by then?

Answer (score 42):

As an airline employee, working with higher management currently, I can *safely* tell you it's a gamble.

The aviation business is like a poor handyman in some poor country, whatever money he makes that day is barely enough for food. If the day goes by without work, no meal that day. This is true even for the best of the airlines. Most of the best five-star world-class airlines out there are living off government support! The rich uncle.

Therefore, unless the airline is supported by the rich uncle, **do not buy the ticket**. The aviation business will eat dirt in 2020 if the COVID situation stays around for a few months, and it's expected that most of the small/medium airlines will bankrupt or get merged with the bigger ones unless they get some serious government support or take serious measures to cut down cost, the support that most governments are using now to fight the COVID-19. Or, some magic pill comes along in the very near future and COVID-19 becomes past in its infancy.

Comment: German press told me that Lufthansa have plenty of reserves.

Comment: @gerrit CEO of WizzAir told [Hungarian media](https://index.hu/gazdasag/2020/03/16/massziv_hiszteria_van_a_jarvany_korul/) that Lufthansa was in trouble (along with Alitalia and Norwegian).

Comment: @user3819867 Everyone is *in trouble*, but I don't know if that's the same as Nean Der Thais handyman allegory, which imho means permanent trouble. Of course Lufthansa is one of the bigger ones.

Comment: @gerrit Lufthansa according to [their 2019 report](https://investor-relations.lufthansagroup.com/fileadmin/downloads/en/financial-reports/financial-statements/LH-FS-2019-e.pdf) had €8 billion short term liabilities paired to €3 billion current assets (€1 billion cash) at the start of the year. This means that unless they have additional money coming in they go bankrupt in a matter of months. Currently they claim to have [€4.3 billion liquidity](https://www.rte.ie/news/business/2020/0319/1124053-lufthansa-on-state-aid/).

Comment: I read something about 3 months of reserves. This would be plenty in a normal situation but it is just about 3 months if almost your whole fleet is grounded and the handful of still existing flights are not even near profitability. In this case it is all your fixed cost plus the loss of the flights that are still kept up

Comment: @NeanDerThal I wish you a happy and fast conversion to some other industry, then!

Comment: @Eric yup, all these elderly people suffocating in phlegm and not quite drawing their last breath and people not being given proper care due to health services being overloaded sure is a perfect time to consider the benefits to climate change. If you truly believe what you are saying you need to true North your moral compass asap.

Comment: @StianYttervik I am pretty sure Eric did not mean it that way. He is specifically talking about air pollution caused by aviation.

Comment: @StianYttervik: Nice strawman, here. NeanDerThal answer only mentions the impact of COVID-19 on civil aviation, so that's what I commented on. The perfect time to consider acting against climate change has been every single day for many decades, and approximately nothing has been really achieved until now. A moral compass doesn't help much if you're trying to solve the [trolley problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_problem). Climate change is causing many thousands of deaths every year already, and it will only get worse.

Comment: @NeanDerThal: Thanks for your fair and cool-headed reaction.

Comment: @Eric If it was a straw man, you had no reason to delete your comment, one wonders. A moral compass is certainly necessary - because if you reduce every challenge you are up against into a "I did it for good reasons" a.k.a. the trolley problem, you are on shady ground. If you believe that any solution to the climate problem, including a murderous disease, is acceptable, you are imho not worthy of a future. Be that as it may, have a nice weekend, reflect on your statements, for your own sake.

Comment: @StianYttervik: My comment got deleted, I still stand by what I wrote. And I really think that climate change (along with our oil dependency) is by far the biggest problem we've ever faced, and is much more devastating than Covid-19. I'm obviously not saying that Covid-19 is the solution to climate change, I'm just saying that some policies against Covid also seem to work well against climate change. Many of those policies have been deemed not doable for decades, but are suddenly on the table. Have a nice week-end too.

Comment: "As an airline employee" God speed man.

Answer (score 23):

Yes and no.  Multiple factors to consider:

1. Flights are cheap on some routes. Cool, what a deal!
2. Like stocks, cheap could be indicative the airline is in trouble
3. If the airline fails ,you may lose your money
4. Borders could still be closed
5. You may or may not get travel insurance
6. You may or may not be at greater risk to Covid-19 exposure.
7. If it flares up, you may not be able to get back if borders close.
8. If you are a carrier at that time, you might actually end up spreading it
9. Any accommodation you book might be closed / go under.
10. Any activities you might want to do might be off access / closed / not operating.

Saying that, disclaimer, I run a [flight deals website](https://www.beatthatflight.com.au/) in Australia and am still promoting deals when I find them, because some people still 'need' to travel (to get back to their countries, to see sick families, etc, not just leisure), and others are wanting to take advantage of the cheap flights like you're suggesting.

So can't answer for any and every case, but while there are deals to be had, you have to decide if perhaps the risks outweigh the benefits.

Comment: great answer! definitely hadn't considered that flair ups are possible or how some airlines might go under.

Comment: Additional risk: when the date of travel rolls round, your personal circumstances might have changed (job, family etc) such that you no longer want to make / can afford to make the trip.

Comment: @sntrenter People have been talking about COVID-19 being like the Spanish Flu in the way it will propagate.  Well the Spanish Flu wasn't a single event.  It actually hit in 3 distinct waves over 1918/1919.  See [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_flu#/media/File:1918_spanish_flu_waves.gif) for example.  So it's quite possible that we could see similar waves of infection with our current situation.

Comment: @PeterM A major reason for the 2nd and 2rd waves, was that the flu was able to continue flourishing and spread  during the sommer months due to the mass transport of malnourished wounded soldiers. So how this flu reacts to the sommer months will be important.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Well its certainly not going to die down just because the weather is warmer.  Otherwise all those countries in the Southern Hemisphere would not have reported all those cases during their local summer.  And given COVID-19's propensity to be contagious when a person is asymptomatic suggests to me that there will be ongoing flare-ups from now on, and that in the short term COVID-19 outbreaks will be the new norm.

Comment: @PeterM Flues, in general, do have a tendency to either die out or become dorment during hot weather. From what I have read this is what the experts will be following carefully to see how this particular virus reacts so that they can estimate what to expect in the winter.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The mention of warmer weather was a facetious reference to a certain president.

Comment: @PeterM Sorry, I haven't the faintest cluecwhat that last statement is suppose to mean, but assume it is something that is off topic.

Comment: Another risk is to be required to self-quarantine at the destination for 2 weeks, like Hawaii is requiring all visitors now.  Which could be all your planned stay at your destination. And another 14 days quarantine on return.